# What do you call the software used in airplane that allow the airplane to fly even if its shape wouldn't allow it to fly?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the software used in airplane that allow the airplane to fly even with a bad shape? I remember there was a name, but I think I forgot it. Does the term apply to other things than airplane? I think modern plane cannot fly without the software.

Comment: By "even with a bad shape", do you mean "even when it is in bad shape"? **autopilot** comes to mind but I'm not sure how it handles a damaged airplane.

Comment: I think you mean a fly-by-wire system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in aeronautics or aerodynamics but I believe the system you may be referring to is called "Fly-by-wire" or more narrowly "Digital Fly-by-wire" or more accurately a "Digital flight control system"

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly-by-wire) for more information.

*Digital flight control systems enable inherently unstable combat aircraft, such as the Lockheed F-117 Nighthawk and the Northrop Grumman B-2 Spirit flying wing to fly in usable and safe manners.*